# Wordpress/IIS/PHP cannot download files with non-ASCII characters

Tags: php, iis, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have a Wordpress installation on a Windows IIS with PHP. It is not possible to download files from the website that have been uploaded with non-ASCII characters. Renaming the files with ASCII characters works fine.

Does anyone know how we can solve this?

Upon trying to download the file an error is received: 404 - File or directory not found. 
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or temporarily unavailable.

Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8 and PHP 5.6.8

Comment: What do you use to download the files? Does the request contain proper encoding of the non-ascii characters?